# Azure devops release pipe line not finding tests

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm new to creating pipelines and working with azure devops, currently working with automated ui tests in visual studio/playwright and am attempting try out running them from a build pipeline and also from Azure test plans using a release pipe line.
So far ive done the following:

Build pipeline
I have set this up and it runs the tests as expected with no issues

Release pipe line:-

- Ive followed the steps detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops), successfully linked my test cases to my automated tests in VS.
- Set up the release pipe line tasks
  When I trigger a release however I get a warning on the vs Test task:

[warning]No test sources found matching the given filter '***,!**\obj**'

The task is not able to find the tests hence they don’t get run.

After some searching I found that I needed to add a release task to copy files.

*Steps Ive tried*
Added a copy files task configured as follows:
Source folder: $(system.defaultworkingdirectory)
Content : **\bin$(BuildConfiguration)** **$(BuildConfiguration)*test*.dll !**\obj**
Target Folder: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)

After adding the copy task and re running a test,  the copy files task succeeds I still get the same warning message in the vsTest task.
I also noticed that the log for the copy task shows that 0 files were found

Ive tried also adding a publish step to publish detailed here but this did not solve the problem.

Is anyone able to help with this issue and point me to the correct settings that I need to use to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, the VsTest task not able to find the test sources and the copy task not able to find the files.

When you create automated UI test in Pipeline, you need to publish the test sources as Build Artifacts in Build Pipeline, then you can download the Artifacts in Release Pipeline and run the test.

Here is an example:

**Build Pipeline:** You need to copy the related test source files to Build Artifacts.

```
steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.4.1'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.4.1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**\*.sln'

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Test Assemblies'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll
     !**\obj\**
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)'
    Contents: '**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

In Release Pipeline, you need to add the Build Artifacts, then the VsTest Task will find the related test source files.

For example:

[image]

On the other hand, in order to run the automated test with Test Plan, you need to add the VsTest Task and select **Test run** option in Release Pipeline.

For example:

[image]